# How to reach the panel of a certain JSlider?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am trying the build a GUI, I have a set of radio buttons and I want a slider to show only when a specific radio button is pressed

I have set the visibility of the panel which contains the slider to false, but I can't reach that panel outside of `AddVehicleDialog` class (because it is a local variable of that class) and I need access for it in `MyActionListener` class.

I tried using `getRootPane()` to get the panel which the slider was added to, but it returned `null`.

```
//AddVehicleDialog.java class
public class AddVehicleDialog extends JDialog {
    // All of the addVehicleDialog buttons, radio buttons and sliders
    JButton okButton, cancelButton;
    static JRadioButton redButton, grnButton, whtButton, svrButton;
    static JRadioButton benzineCar, solarCar, bikeRadButton, carriageRadButton;
    JSlider gearsSlider;

    public AddVehicleDialog() {
        setTitle("Add a vehicle to the city");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(550, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setModal(true);

        // OK & Cancel buttons & radio buttons
        addVehicleDialogButtons();
    }


//bike's gears slider - part of addVehicleDialogButtons() method;

        gearsSlider = new JSlider(0, 10);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel gearsLabel = new JLabel("Choose bike's gears");

        gearsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        gearsLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        centerPanel.add(gearsLabel);
        gearsSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        gearsSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        gearsSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        gearsSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        gearsSlider.setExtent(0);
        centerPanel.add(gearsSlider,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        centerPanel.setVisible(false);
        this.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

//MyActionListener class is in a different file from centerPanel component


public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        .
        .
        .
        case "OK":
            if (AddVehicleDialog.bikeRadButton.isSelected()) {
                //this is what i want to do
                centerPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

I know I can't reach `centerPanel`, because it is a local variable of `AddVehicleDialog` class.

I've made the `gearsSlider` static so I could reach him in `MyActionListener` class

I don't think it is a good practice to put `centerPanel` as static, but I can't think of other way to reach this specific panel outside of the class.

I hope it is understandable enough. If more clarification is needed, please tell and I'll provide.

The panel when visibility set to false:

[image]

The way I want the panel to look when I select Bike radio button.

[image]

Comment: Note: Javascript != Java. Please choose tags carefully for these completely distinct programming languages.

Comment: I am pretty sure i've made the tag java, but thanks for editing it!

Comment: 1) *"pretty sure i've made the tag java"* Check the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55708586/revisions) to confirm it, if you like.. 2) *"I don't think it is a good practice to put `centerPanel` as `static`"* You'd be right in that thinking. Having to make GUI components static is usually a sign the design need changing. One way that access / scope becomes a problem is by extending components or windows like `JDialog` unnecessarily. Why not simply use a standard `JDialog` and customize it as needed? 3) `//this is what i want to do centerPanel.setVisible(true);`  probably ..

Comment: .. better to use a `CardLayout` in which one card is an empty panel, then flip to the required panel on action. This then allows the use of `pack()` to determine the right size, as opposed to `setSize(550, 300);` .. guessing. It might need to be larger on other systems or PLAFs. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This is part of my HW1 in my B.Sc in Program engineering, so I must have the same classes signature as they show. I also added a photos of what I wish my GUI would have looked like

Comment: *"I must have the same classes signature as they show"* Was that about extending dialog? This is a good time to be adding more details, rather than less.

Comment: Yeah it was about extending the`JDialog`, I think you delivered me my answer with that `CardLayout` option, I will give it a try. Thanks a lot for your patience and explanation

Comment: "I know I can't reach centerPanel, because it is a local variable of AddVehicleDialog class" - that is not correct: you can get any variable that you **want** to expose. One simple way is a getter method: `public JPanel getCenterPanel{return centerPanel;}`

Comment: *"I will give it a try."* How did it go?

Comment: The `CardLayout` was the perfect solution for me, thank you so much!